# Storing API key on mobile device

Tags: android, ios, authentication, mobile, oauth-2.0

*I've read many, if not all, answers to previously asked questions about the same topic, but questions themselves are not exactly about my case.*

I have an OAuth 2.0 server running. It has an endpoint that provides access tokens to users. Programs and websites requesting the access token may or may not be owned by me, in other words, I may add a tool for website users and locate it on the same or neighboring website and my users may create an app and with their API key request access to user's data. Now I am developing the app that will operate user's data.

I realize that storing the API secret on the device is not a good solution. I have read about creating an end-point to which I make request directly from the app and then the endpoint makes API requests, but the endpoint will have to exist on the same host and probably server as OAuth server.

Is there a way to authorize mobile application to access user data when I am in controll of the application and the OAuth server? Should I create a separate end-point? Should I pass it device ID and/or any other information?

**P.S.** I know that plain old authorization would work here, but then what if some user wants to create his own mobile extension (not allowed currently for security reasons)? Also, current system has a button that is recognized by many people and they know what exactly will happen after clicking it. With the app, it may be an issue when the user sees a login dialog instead of the "Login with *" button. I really hope there is a clever solution to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your concern is spot on. Your API Secret should not be stored on the device.

However, I am not sure why you would be concerned to build a separate endpoint, since OAuth 2 has a authorization flow for these use cases.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-9

In your use case, I'd suggest using the implicit grant flow to fetch the access token and store that on the local device. There would be no refresh tokens and the access_token can have an expiration date. Of course, the token on the device can be compromised, but the damage will be limited to a particular user and not the entire application.

If this level of security is not acceptable, then you can look at splitting up your API Secret in different parts of your app and then assemble it at run time in your app.